# Are there any word types in English that don't fall into one of these 5 functional categories?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, semantics, parts-of-speech, functions

(And I suppose the logical follow-up question is - are there any functions words take that are not included in these 5 categories?)

1) *deliver specific content/ meaning*

- adjective
- adverb
- noun
- verb

2) *establish relationships* between other words, phrases and parts of sentences

- conjunction
- wh-word
- pronoun
- prepositions
- copulas (link verbs)

3) *modify or refine* the meaning of another word, phrase or sentence

- adjective
- adverb
- determiner
- numeral
- negative
- noun
- preposition
- modals

4) *frame a question*

- wh-word
- modals
- be, do and have (??)

5) *Establish verb tense and time reference*

- adverbs
- nouns
- prepositions
- auxiliaries
- verb participles

Maybe interjections, particles, lexemes (but it seems that once these words find context in a sentence they would fall into one of the above functional categories)?

Comment: Wow, that's a good question, but, oh dear, I don't think interjections necessarily fall into any of those categories.

Comment: Your category 1 ("deliver meaningful content") might cover the lot.

Comment: Lyrical fillers. / I don't think that this breakdown is particularly helpful. For instance, the category 'establish relationships between other words, phrases and parts of sentences' lumps prepositions, which primarily tie things together at a semantic level  (He went to the bank for some money) with ordering pragmatic markers (...; second, he went to the bank), whose function is similar to numbers in a numbered list. You might like to look at articles and other treatments (eg by Fraser, Swan) on pragmatic / discourse markers, which have plenty of subdivisions.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Not helpful in what way? I'm always aiming at generalizing grammar and linguistic concepts for ESL pedagogy - because language learners do not understand complex linguistic concepts (nor do they want to) and are unable to internalize them usefully - I just want to be sure I'm not getting something horribly wrong, which is why I ask here. But we all are able to do these things, like using ordering pragmatic markers, without understanding them analytically.  Secondly, I think these kind of generalized grammar concepts are easier to assimilate and use naturally/ subconsciously.

Comment: I do see your point about numeral words which can modify entire clauses.

Comment: Is punctuation technically a word type? (haha)

Comment: @BoldBen - I think interjections would fall into category 1) Deliver meaningful content

Comment: There have been numerous attempts to define word classes in a scheme superior to that consisting of the 8 classes of antiquity. Though some disagree, many think that form and relation to concept involved (an object referent? change we could see happening on a video?) as well as syntactic function / distribution should play a part in the classification of words. Professional academics have spent years arguing the pros and cons of various classification schemes. / Like Lawrence, I can see classification problems with your suggestion here (though I wouldn't agree with his implied comment)....

Comment: Usually, words are divided into two large sets, lexical/content and  functional/structure (after Fries, 1952). [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word) gives a raw introduction to the topic. You could use it as a research tool; it gives some subclasses of function words. But, for example, the preposition _on_ in  'I put it on the table' carries obvious semantic weight as well as serving a relating role within the sentence. Again, I find it useful and sensible to have a set of 'extra-sentential' elements, like the traditionally labelled 'sentence adverbial'.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I love the nuances linguistic analysis finds in language. It shows me so much but I swear, I'm not proposing a scheme to be useful at that level of classification; it's just for language training. I think, the way I'm generalizing, words are on a l/c --> f/s gradient, that's why word types appear in multiple categories. I can't think of a word that doesn't have  some of both sides in the context of language.

Comment: @Lawrence - I've refined the category name, which as you point out wasn't distinctive enough (thanks). Obviously, all words deliver content, but these words have specific meaning even without the context provided by surrounding text. The exception in the list is pronouns, but their referent provides the specificity. Maybe they don't really belong in this category because the same could be said for the other types in the primarily functional categories. I think the difference is that some words depend on context for complete meaning, while other deliver their meaning independent of context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62264/discussion-between-ubu-english-and-edwin-ashworth).

Answer (score 1):

"Yes" and "no" are hard to classify.

From Wikipedia [Yes and no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no):

> The words yes and no are not easily classified into any of the eight conventional parts of speech. Although sometimes classified as interjections, they do not qualify as such, and they are not adverbs. They are sometimes classified as a part of speech in their own right, sentence words, word sentences, or pro-sentences, although that category contains more than yes and no and not all linguists include them in their lists of sentence words. Sentences consisting solely of one of these two words are classified as minor sentences.

The Oxford Dictionary defines them as "exclamations":

- https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yes
- https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/no

However, they also define [hello](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hello) as an exclamation, seemly using it to mean "interjection".